# Benefit to smaller bottles?

Tags: equipment, bottling

Im about to bottle my first 5 gal batch that i have made in a while, and am considering buying some 22oz bottles to try to reduce the amount of time i spend cleaning bottles, but am wondering if the convenience comes at any cost.  Do the smaller 12oz bottles have any benefit to the conditioning, or carbonation of the beer?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

In short the biggest convenience of 12oz v 22oz is that you don't have to drink two-ish beers when you want one.

There isn't any noticeable difference in my experience between the carbonation amount in on versus the other.

Comment: Seconded.  I also like standard 12 ouncers because you can give your beer away in them and not worry about getting them back.

Comment: thirded :) I bottle in 22oz and do about 4 in 12 oz per 5 gallon batch. I then use those for testers so that I am not opening a 22oz beer that isn't perfect.

Comment: Fourthed - Heh on the biggest beers, such as a Chimay Blue clone we make, we use big swing-tops, but still make a few 12oz bottles too, for when we don't want the quantity.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, there is little difference; however, with the way we typically bottle, the volume to headspace (remaining volume of air) will be different, which may affect attenuation and conditioning.
The inverse reason to why it's not a good idea to only fill a bottle half way.